# mpris-remote doesn't pick up pithos

Tags: terminal, xfce4

I am using pithos on debian 9 with xfce.

I am looking for a simple way to control it with the command line.

I installed mpris-remote but when I run it, it says:

```
$ mpris-remote
No MPRIS-compliant player found running.
```

How do I get it to work?

Or, do you have any working solutions for controlling pithos from the command line?

Pianobar is out becuase I need a GUI as well.

Answer (score 1):

`mpris-remote` (the Debian version) was written for MPRIS v1, while Pithos only supports the MPRIS v2 interface. (Practically all players now use only v2.)

You will need to use another client, such as [playerctl](https://github.com/acrisci/playerctl), this other [mpris-remote](https://github.com/c0decat/mpris-remote), or my [mpris](https://nullroute.eu.org/:r/code/mpris).

The API is somewhat easy to use directly via `busctl call` or `gdbus call` as well.

```
busctl --user --acquired | grep mpris
gdbus introspect -e -d org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.pithos -o /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2
```

Comment: I had some trouble with the installation of playerctl.
I ran:
``sudo ./autogen.sh --prefix=/opt/playerctl``

and

``sudo make install``

Everything seemed to work fine, but when I tried to run it is said command not found.

Comment: If you install it to a nonstandard path, you need to specify it in full when running the command.

Comment: I used the full path. It said that it was missing a library.
`` error while loading shared libraries: libplayerctl-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory``
I tried recompiling it after setting this env variable ``export LDFLAGS="-rpath /path/to/library "$LDFLAGS``. It didn't help.
I tried running ``libtool --mode=finish /opt/playerctl/libplayerctl-1.0.so.0``, I got this error: ``libtool:   error: invalid argument '/opt/playerctl/libplayerctl-1.0.so.0``.